# Comparar nombre de columnas de dos data frame

Tags: r

Quiero comparar el número de columnas de dos df. Algo como esto pero bien hecho.

```
df1 <- iris
df2 <- iris[ , -c(3,4)]


resul <-
  if (ncol(df1)==ncol(df2)) {
    paste("Los dos ficheros tienen las mismas columnas:",ncol(df1))
  } else { 
    
    if ( ncol(df1) > ncol(df2) ){
      paste("El fichero df1 tiene", ncol(df1)-ncol(df2),"columnas más que el df2", "\n","\n",
            "Columnas que están en df1 y no están en df2:",names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)==FALSE])
      
    }
    else {
      paste("El fichero df2 tiene", ncol(df2)-ncol(df1) ,"columnas más que el df1", "\n","\n",
                "Columnas que están en df2 y no están en df1:", names(df2)[names(df2) %in% names(df1)==FALSE])
    }
  }

resul
```

No tengo claro como hacer para que salga el resultado en una sola línea. He probado con pasarlo a vector, lista, usar setdiff etc y nada. No sé si con `ifelse` en vez de `if` saldría mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas lo puedes conseguir con el siguiente código, aunque me queda la duda de que debería pasar si el numero de columnas en `df1` es igual al de `df2` pero los nombres de dichas columnas no son iguales

```
df1 <- iris
df2 <- iris[ , -c(3,4)]


resul <-
  if (ncol(df1)==ncol(df2)) {
    paste("Los dos ficheros tienen las mismas columnas:",ncol(df1))
  } else { 
    
    if ( ncol(df1) > ncol(df2) ){
      paste("El fichero df1 tiene", ncol(df1)-ncol(df2),"columnas más que el df2", "\n","\n",
            "Columnas que están en df1 y no están en df2:",
            paste0(names(df1)[!(names(df1) %in% names(df2))],collapse=", "))
      
    }
    else {
      paste("El fichero df2 tiene", ncol(df2)-ncol(df1) ,"columnas más que el df1", "\n","\n",
                "Columnas que están en df2 y no están en df1:", 
                paste0(names(df2)[!(names(df2) %in% names(df1))],collapse=", "))
    }
  }

resul

cat(resul)
```

Para que solo arroje una linea utilizamos el argumentó `collapse=", "` a la función `paste0` que reduce los elementos de un vector a solo uno de tipo character.

Luego para lograr obtener los nombres de un df que no estan en el otro usamos `names[!(names(df2) %in% names(df1))]` en lugar de `names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)==FALSE]`